# Is there a way to pull a list of all user that have ever authenticated to a Twitter Application?

Tags: twitter

I am unable to find this in the documentation but I know FaceBook has something similar where, as the App you can pull a list of all users that have authenticated ( or granted permissions ) to said App.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter REST API does not expose any methods that allow developers to see who has authorized their application.